# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{n+ln(n)}}{n^n}$ with root test

Tags: calculus, summation

If I'm only using root test (not calculating, and not using other tests) then is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{n+ln(n)}}{n^n}$ useful nor not useful for the root test? It's useful when the limit is not 1.

When I calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{e^{n+ln(n)}}{n^n})^{\frac{1}{n}}$, it's 0. Then the root test works.

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: $e^{n+\log(n)}=ne^n$ makes life easier for any test

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici the question is does root test work. It works here yes?